# Template 2.5.1 installation issue on macos

Tags: macos, monodevelop, monogame

Monogame 2.5.1 template is not working for me on MacOS, MonoDev 3.0.3.4

I did the following but still no template:

1. Shutdown MonoDevelop
2. Find your MonoDevelop AppBundle
3. Right Click on it and select "Show package Contents"
4. Press Alt and Drag and Drop the directory MonoDevelop.MonoGame.2.5 into ../Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/

After doing the above multiple times, it still did not work.  Next, I tried the same steps above but with MonoDevelop.MonoGame.1.6.0 and this time, in MonoDevelop "Add-in Manager" I do see a >Templates > MonoGame Project Template.  with the following message: " This add-in can't be loaded due to missing depencies"

Basically, MonoDevelop.MonoGame.2.5 doesn't show up in "Add-in Manager" and doesn't work, MonoDevelop.MonoGame.1.6.0 does show up but not working.

Does anyone have know what's going on.

Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I've been having this problem too, and it's really frustrating me.

Comment: Hmm, its awfully suspicious that under `templates`, there are files called `MonoGameAndroidProject.xpt.xml`, `MonoGameLinuxProject.xpt.xml`, and `MonoGameWindowsProject.xpt.xml`, but nothing for Mac... Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: It looks like for the 1.6.0 template to work, you need MonoDevelop 2.4.